# Making jQuery's .prev().prev().prev().find("selector") calls easier

Tags: jquery

How can I avoid the `.prev().prev().prev()` calls? Is there a shortcut for this?

Answer (score 27):

You can use `.prevAll`, combined with `eq` or `:eq`, since `prevAll` returns a set of element in the reverse order starting with the element that's closest to the current element being `[0]`, the equivalent to `.prev().prev().prev()` would be `.prevAll().eq(2)` or `.prevAll(':eq(2)')`.

See this simple demo: http://www.jsfiddle.net/QZYHN/

Comment: There is also [.prevUntil(selector)](https://api.jquery.com/prevUntil/).

Answer (score 7):

You can do `prevAll()` with a selector.

```
$('div').prevAll('a:last')
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `closest` which searches for the nearest ancestor that matches the selector. eg.

```
$(this).closest('table').find('selector')
```

**Edit:** Added find() at the end

Comment: `prev` doesn't look up, this isn't really the same.

Comment: My original code was:         $('#tableid tr:last').prev().prev().prev().find("img").click(function() { ... but 
        $('#tableid tr:last').closest("img").click(function() { is not working :(

Answer (score -2):

take a look at `nth-child` in jquery, might be of help...