# Jquery prev() tr where value is not empty

Tags: jquery

I have an table with +- 30 (one for each day of the month) rows and input fields start_km[] and end_km[] in each row also with class start_km and end_km respectively.

Basely what I need to do is when entering start_km say for instance on the 4th row it needs to get the value of end_km in the 3rd row to test if they are the same. Now that is easily done with:

```
$(this).parent().parent('tr').prev('tr').find('.end_km').val();
```

My problem is that the 3rd row may be empty so I need to go to the 2nd row. I know I can do it with:

```
$(this).parent().parent('tr').prev('tr').prev('tr').find('.end_km').val();
```

Now I'm sure you can see my problem, my entry can be on the 30th row and the last entry can be on the 4th row so that's allot of if's and prev()'s.

Is there an faster or cleaner way to do this?

Thanks for your input on this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making jQuery's .prev().prev().prev().find("selector") calls easier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4921247/making-jquerys-prev-prev-prev-findselector-calls-easier)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the `prevAll().eq(x)` method combination

This makes it possible to select the previous element that equals the x position in relation to the 'original' element

```
prevAll().eq(0) = prev()
prevAll().eq(1) = prev().prev()
prevAll().eq(2) = prev().prev().prev()
...
```

Check [Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/vj6h7sr7/)

Answer (score 0):

I've created a function for you. You just have to add it in you file and call it. Here how it goes :

```
$.fn.firstPrevMatch = function(match){
    var $prev = this.prev(); //Get the prev element
    if($prev.length){//Check if it exist
        var $match = $prev.filter(match); //If it does, compare it to your match
        if($match.length) return $match.first(); //If it match, return the first element
        else return $prev.firstPrevMatch(match); //Else, recall the function with the previous elememnt
    }else{
        return this.not('*'); //First-child, return empty object
    }
}
```

Once it is included, you will be able to use it like that :

```
$(this).closest('tr').firstPrevMatch(function(){
    return $(this).find('.end_km').val();
}).find('.end_km').val();
```

[Here's a live **example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lu1rb8ec/)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for the quick response, both of your answers gave me what I need.

I ended up doing this:

```
for (i = 0; i <= 30; i++) {
 ekl = $(this).parent().parent('tr').prevAll('tr').eq(i).find('.end_km').val();
  if (ekl != '') {
   alert(ekl);   
   break 
  }         
}
```